# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute ''index"

Tags: python, recursion, attributeerror

In python, I'm trying to get a depth of recursion(dor).  Before adding all the dor things into my code, it worked ~fine, but after adding the dor stuff, I received an attribute error concerning my code.  Here is the function where I'm receiving the error

```
 def parse(json,dor=0):
      parse.index[dor]=0
      parse.keyList[dor]=[]
      parse.jsonDict[dor]=dict()
      parse.json[dor]=remove_white(json)
```

Comment: You have a function called `parse` and you're modifying a variable called `parse`, which refers to your function. Can you post all of your code?

Comment: `parse.index` etc are some attributes of this very function `parse`, where are they assigned? You may want to consider a class instead.

Comment: @Blender I'd prefer not to since it's a 270 line monstrosity

Comment: @LukeMaresca: 270 lines is *tiny*.

Comment: @bereal can I take off the parse. in this def and refer to it as parse.[something] throughout the rest of my code

Comment: `parse` refers to the function you have defined, and your function does not have index attribute

Comment: @avasal Why the heck did the code compile and work(- the recursion) before I added the [dor]

Comment: @LukeMaresca: Just paste all of your code. There's no point in debugging code that we can't actually see.

Comment: It did work because you were assigning an attribute, which is weird and highly thread-unsafe, but legit. Now you're making `parse.index[dor] = 0` which is roughly equivalent to `parse.index.__setitem__(dor, 0)` and is supposed to fail exactly like described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer: what you are doing is most likely The Wrong Thing To Do**

Your code worked before because (I assume) you were setting an attribute on a function object:

```
def foo():
  foo.bar = 4
```

When run, the function object sets an attribute `bar` on itself. However, when you added the `__setitem__` (with the square brackets):

```
def foo():
  foo.bar[dor] = 4
```

You're now saying that you want to modify `foo.bar`, but `foo.bar` doesn't exist yet! You can "fix" this by setting up the object manually, before you run it for the first time:

```
def foo():
  foo.bar[dor] = 4

foo.bar = {}
foo()
```

Most likely, you want to avoid this whole mess altogether by using a separate object to keep track of the recursion depth in your code. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

EDIT: Looking at your code, it seems like you should be using a class instead of a function for `parse`. Using a class makes sense because you're encapsulating mutable state with a set of methods that act on it. Of course, I'm also obligated to point you to [the standard library JSON module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).